# How to dynamically allocate 2d array that's 16B aligned

Tags: c, arrays, allocation, memory-alignment

I'd like to allocate 2D array (square matrix) using `memalign` with 16B instead of using just `malloc`.

I have

```
A =(float **) malloc( (*dim) * sizeof(float*));
for ( i = 0 ; i < (*dim) ; i++) {

    A[i] = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*(*dim));
}
```

how can I change code above with `memalign`.

Answer (score 4):

With `malloc()` you need to request 15 extra bytes and then round-up the returned pointer to the nearest multiple of 16, e.g.:

```
void* p = malloc(size + 15);
void* paligned;
if (!p) { /* handle errors */ }
paligned = (void*)(((size_t)p + 15) / 16 * 16);
/* use paligned */
free(p);
```

Comment: Nice, platform independent answer

Answer (score 2):

What you have here isn't really a 2D matrix, just a 1D array pointing at more 1D arrays.

Do you want something like this instead?

```
A = (float*) memalign(16, (*dim) * (*dim) * sizeof(float));
```

This will generate you a 1D array which is dim^2 elements long. This is how 2D arrays are usually used in C/C++ (unless you have a specific reason to use an array of pointers to other arrays).

I assume you wish to feed this array into some DSP function - It is hard to know more without knowing the function you are trying to use.

If you must have access to the array as A[x][y], you could do this:

```
float *aMemory = (float*) memalign(16, (*dim) * (*dim));
float **A = (float**) malloc(*dim * sizeof(float));
for (i = 0; i < *dim; i++)
{
    A[i] = &aMemory[*dim * i];
}
```

Now you can access the array aMemory through the array of pointers A, as

```
// A[row][column]
A[0][0] = 0.0f;
A[1][1] = 1.0f;
```

etc.

Comment: I'm trying to do matrix transpose/5-point stencil/matirx multiplication on a square matrix and I thought to use intrinsic functions the array needs to be aligned.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question specific to the functions you are trying to use, you might get more useful information :) I am not sure what you mean by intrinsic functions. I am not even sure what platform/compiler/etc you are using.

Comment: If I declare it as float* with size of dim^2, will I be able to access the array with 2 index? for example, Can I still do A[x][y] even though A is declared as float *?

Comment: No. You can't - you would need to do something like A[x+y*dim] - if you want your array to be in row-major order.

Comment: by Intrinsic I mean I'm trying to use SSE instructions (xmm registers) and I'm using mac/gcc4.7 .

Comment: I see, So If I want to index the array with [x][y] I need to allocate memory the way I initially did. Is there a way to keep that format (array inside array) and align it to 16B?

Comment: If `*dim` is replaced with a constant (e.g. 5), one can declare a pointer to an array of floats: `float (*A)[5];`, allocate memory to it `A=malloc(5*5*sizeof(float)+15)`, align it (as shown in my answer) and then use it as `A[x][y]`. Just one allocation, no loops. If the compiler supports VLAs (variable-length arrays), the constant 5 may be replaced back by a variable's value, `*dim` or some such.

Comment: I edited my answer, but I really wouldn't recommend anybody actually do the second part. I actually am not sure if it is faster or not, it certainly uses more indirection and thus an optimising compiler may not produce code which is as good (compact, fast) as the A[x+y*(*dim)] case.

Comment: If I declare A with : float (*A)[5] what is the type of A? I want to pass A to a function by pointer.( so that I can modify the matrix from the function).

Comment: @kiki: `float (*A)[5]` then A is a pointer-to-array-of-5-floats. In the same way that you can use an `int*` (pointer-to-int) to point to the first element of an array of `int`, you can use `A` to point to the first element of an array-of-arrays, provided that the second dimension of that array-of-arrays is `5`. Then `A[0][0]` refers to the first element of the first element of that array-of-arrays.